# How to avoid connection establishing on every client request?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I am implementing a WCF rest service along with SCOM . From service i am establishing connection to SCOM server when client request for alert data.
As alert requesting is happening for every 2 mins to don't want to establish connection every time a single connection should stay like never expired if connection is not available then establish connection.here is sample code.

```
public void SCOM_ConnectionSettings()
        {
            System.Security.SecureString ss = new System.Security.SecureString();

            ss.AppendChar('x');
            ss.AppendChar('x');
            ss.AppendChar('x');
            ss.AppendChar('d');
            ss.AppendChar('x');
            ss.AppendChar('x');


            ManagementGroupConnectionSettings mgGroupConnection = new ManagementGroupConnectionSettings("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx");
            mgGroupConnection.CacheMode = CacheMode.None;
            mgGroupConnection.Domain = "IMTS.Test";
            mgGroupConnection.UserName = "Azureuser";

            mgGroupConnection.Password = ss;
            mgGroup = new ManagementGroup(mgGroupConnection);


        }
```

main method calling alerts

```
  public List<MonitoringObject> GetNewAssetInformation()
        {
            SCOM_ConnectionSettings();
            List<MonitoringObject> monitoringobjects = new List<MonitoringObject>();

            AgentManagedComputerCriteria agentCriteria = new AgentManagedComputerCriteria("LastModified >= '" + new DateTime(2015, 5, 25).ToString("G") + "'");//LastModified >= '" + new DateTime(2006, 10, 25).ToString("G") + "'");

            ManagementGroupAdministration administration = mgGroup.GetAdministration();
            ReadOnlyCollection<AgentManagedComputer> agents = administration.GetAgentManagedComputers(agentCriteria);
            if (agents.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (AgentManagedComputer agentManagedComputer in agents)
                {
                    if (agentManagedComputer.InstallTime >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
                    {
                        monitoringobjects.Add(mgGroup.GetMonitoringObject(agentManagedComputer.Id));
                    }

                }
                return monitoringobjects;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Use a static connection

Comment: Unless you know SCOM allows multiple requests using the same object, you should not piggy back multiple requests on a single connection. So a _static connection_ may be unwise.  Consider using a pool of ready-to-go connections, one per incoming REST thread.  You'll need to implement some form of keep-alive.